# run_av (ClamAV-clamd) and ClamAV-clamd av-scanner FAILED - unexpected

Tags: amavis, clamav

I get a strange error when scanning email.

```
Sep 17 15:13:26 mail amavis[616]: (00616-02) (!)run_av (ClamAV-clamd) FAILED - unexpected , output="/var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20140917T141903-00616-Vqttx7KO/parts: lstat() failed: Permission denied. ERROR\n"
Sep 17 15:13:26 mail amavis[616]: (00616-02) (!)ClamAV-clamd av-scanner FAILED: CODE(0xf8fde0) unexpected , output="/var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20140917T141903-00616-Vqttx7KO/parts: lstat() failed: Permission denied. ERROR\n" at (eval 113) line 899.
Sep 17 15:13:26 mail amavis[616]: (00616-02) (!)WARN: all primary virus scanners failed, considering backups
```

I added amavis to clamav group and vice versa but I think its not the trick.
can somebody help?

please comment so I add necessary infos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In clamd.conf AllowSupplementaryGroups is default false

try this:

```
AllowSupplementaryGroups true
```

Answer (score 0):

That solution above is now deprecated:

clamd[24691]: WARNING: Ignoring deprecated option AllowSupplementaryGroups at /etc/clamav/clamd.conf:88

Comment: Unfortunately, Dave is right.
That behavior is actually since OS patch during November. Before that Clamav was working just fine without any issues or such complains. Cheers,
-Tiho